# How do I parse a date/time format using strptime() function?

Tags: shell, perl

How do I parse a date/time format using the strptime() function?

The data/time format to be converted is:
e.g. Tue Jan 16 11:18:20 + 000 2018

Comment: This almost looks like a default output of the [date](https://linux.die.net/man/1/date) utility. If `+ 000` is a typo and there isn't actually a space after the `+`, the str(pf)time pattern would be `%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %z %Y`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The man pages for [strptime](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html) show the API details as well as an example for C.

In Perl, the [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) module (which is part of the Perl core), provides the `strptime` function.  Examples are contained in the module's documentation.

For example, this Perl snippet will convert the date as formatted to an ISO 8601 notation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;
my $t = Time::Piece->strptime
    ("Tue Jan 16 11:18:20 +0000 2018", "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y");
print $t->strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S\n");
```

...producing the output:

```
2018-01-16T11:18:20
```

A shorthand way of producing the ISO date is simply:

```
print $t->datetime, "\n";
```

whereas you can obtain the corresponding epoch seconds thusly:

```
print $t->epoch, "\n";
```

Thus,`strptime` converts a string of a time's description (its first argument) into its components, based upon the definition of its pieces in its second argument. `strftime` is the converse operation, converting time components of a time structure loaded by `strptime`, into a string description.

Comment: Are you able to explain what "Time::Piece;" does? Also how come at the last line, strftime is used, not strptime? :)

Comment: @Nate, `use Time::Piece;` loads the module, and `strptime` isn't used in the last line because the last line doesn't attempt to parse a date-time string.

Comment: @Nate Think "(str)ing (p)arse" for `strptime`; Think "(str)ing (f)ormat" for `strftime`.